# Object in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I use BroadcastReceiver for manage my app behaviour when incoming call.
I need to access to object instantiated in my MAIN activity.
In my main activity I create an object with any method that I need to execute in BroadcastReceiver.

How can I access to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object you add in intent and send through broadcast, your object must implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

Comment: How can i do this ? I need to manage MediaPlayer object in BroadcastReceiver: is it Parcelable ?

Comment: no, that class doesn't implement Parcelable. Instead, I suggest you to create your own class which holds important fields/variables to reproduce MediaPlayer object and make this class Parcelable

Comment: How can i do this ? In my example I need to manage volume: how can i use mMediaPlayer.setVolume() in BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: why dont you simply pass `int` value for volume through your broadcast?

Comment: I solved using Singleton that extends MediaPlayer, so i sure to get the ONLY existing instance. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new class which  extends Application, in this class create a global variable with getter and setter methods

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  private YourTypeObject object;
  public void setObj(YourTypeObject  obj )
  {
    object=obj;
  }
  public YourTypeObject getObj()
  {
    return object;
  }
  ...
}
```

In your MAIN activity you can use

```
...
YourTypeObject myobj=....
MyApplication  application = (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
application.setObj(myobj);
...
```

Now in your another Activity you can use

```
...
MyApplication  application = (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
YourTypeObject obj=getObj();
...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for because the poster said one of the classes is a BroadcastReceiver, not an Activity.